# $R^2$ for mixed models with multiple fixed and random effects

Tags: r, mixed-model, r-squared

I have a mixed model with three random effects and many fixed effects.  I set aside some of my data to validate my final model and now I would like to compute the $R^2$ on the validation set, in `R`.

I found some code for a mixed model with one random effect but not for a model with more than one random. Does anyone know a package or some code to compute $R^2$ for mixed models with more than one random effect?  If this isn't possible, does anyone have a good suggestion for comparing model fits?

Comment: The `lme4` package in `R` can estimate mixed effects models with more than one random effect. Because a mixed effects model isn't exactly analogous to a linear model without random effects, there isn't an easy direct equivalent for $R^2$. However, this paper by Gelman and Pardoe might be useful to you: http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/004017005000000517

Answer (score 4):

One possible approach was suggested by [Nakagawa and Schielzeth (2013)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.2041-210x.2012.00261.x/abstract) where $R^2$ is decomposed into variance explained by fixed effects ($R^2_m$) and random effects ($R^2_c$).

Let's say your model looks like the one below, where $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ are random effects:

$$y_{ijk} = \beta_0 + \sum^M_{m=1} \beta_m X_{mijk} + \alpha_j + \gamma_k + \epsilon_{ijk}$$

if so, you can define $R^2$ for fixed effects as:

$$R^2_m = \frac{\sigma^2_f}{\sigma^2_f + \sigma^2_\alpha + \sigma^2_\gamma + \sigma^2_\epsilon}$$

where:

$$\sigma^2_f = var\left( \sum^M_{m=1} \beta_m X_{mijk} \right)$$

And $R^2$ for random effects as:

$$R^2_c = \frac{\sigma^2_f + \sigma^2_\alpha + \sigma^2_\gamma}{\sigma^2_f + \sigma^2_\alpha + \sigma^2_\gamma + \sigma^2_\epsilon}$$

And this approach could be extended to GLMM's by decomposing $\sigma^2_\epsilon$ into (Nakagawa and Schielzeth, 2013, p. 137):

> (i) multiplicative dispersion ($\omega$), (ii) additive dispersion
>   ($\sigma^2_e$) and (iii) distribution-specific variance ($\sigma^2_d$)

[Johnson (2014)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/2041-210X.12225/abstract) suggested how this approach could be used for random slopes models.

Functions for estimating $R^2_m$ and $R^2_c$ can be found in [MuMIn package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MuMIn/index.html) using `r.squaredGLMM` function.